# Match elements with same name inside an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I have the following code that get all my filter elements and echo each of them with a Title (getName) and its inner elements (getHtml). What I want is to check the titles and merge the equal ones to show all inner elements together without repeating equal titles.

For example, if I have a filter named FILTER-AB with element 1 and 2, and a second filter also named FILTER-AB with elements 3 and 4, I want to echo just one table with title FILTER-AB and inner elements 1, 2, 3 and 4. **See easier example below**

**EDIT** For instance, the HTML elements are a list of elements, those which are not of great importance here. The Filter name is taken by the "getName" method on third line (written then as a dt class) and the elements are taken by "getHtml" method on 7th line (written then as inner Html elements  dd class)

I could not think any method to do this, please any help or guidance would be appreciated!

```html
<?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
             <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                   <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                                 (Not important line)      <?php if($_searchFilter !== false): ?>
                                 (Not important line)        <dt class="attribute_value_search_box<?php if($_searchFilter !== true): ?> enabled<?php endif; ?>"><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Search for option'); ?>" /></dt>
                                 (Not important line)      <?php endif;?>
                   <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
             <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**EXAMPLE (What I have now)**

```html
<dt class="even">Brand</dt>
<dd class="even">
    <li>
Element 1
    </li>   
</dd>
<dt class="odd">Brand</dt>
<dd class="odd">
    <li>
Element 2
    </li>   
</dd>
<dt class="even">Type</dt>
<dd class="even">
    <li>
Element 3
    </li>   
</dd>
```

**RESULT EXPECTED**

```html
<dt class="even">Brand</dt>
<dd class="even">
    <li>
Element 1
    </li>
    <li>
Element 2
    </li>
</dd>
<dt class="odd">Type</dt>
<dd class="odd">
    <li>
Element 3
    </li>   
</dd>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you do this server side by fixing your data first. If you do it client side in JS you'll most likely get a FOUC before the JS executes which is really jarring for your users

Comment: I think I can't do it that way since my filter list is dependant to the product collection that is being displayed on the page the user is viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your data to a grouped array of arrays using the `name` as key. Then iterate that array to generate the html

Something like:

```
<?php 
$data = array();
foreach ($_filters as $_filter) {
    if ($_filter->getItemsCount()) {
        $name = $this->$_filter->getName();           
        $data[$name][] = $_filter->getHtml();
    }
?>

<?php foreach ($data as $name => $items): ?>
   <dl>
        <dt><?php echo $name ?>
            <dl>
                <dt class="attribute_value_search_box<?php if ($_searchFilter !== true): ?> enabled<?php endif; ?>">
                <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Search for option'); ?>">
                </dt>
                <?php foreach ($items as $html): ?>
                    <dd><?php echo $html ?></dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
           </dl>
        </dt>
   </dl>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am doing some modifications, but the idea seems to work. I am getting though multiple echos for the same title until it finnaly merge the elements.. thanks for the tip!

Comment: Very common to need to map your data to meet your needs ..both in server side code and in client side code